# Data not binded to C# ListView (after second attempt)

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, data-binding

I am trying to use a ListView to pull in data from a database. It "works" on the first try if the value exists, but it has a problem when searching for values that don't and then trying again with any other value(even if that other value does exist).

When debugging, I noticed the following:

If I search for a value that doesn't exist in thedatabase, then try to search for one that does, the debugger goes from the line "bValid = true" directly to the method to get the data for the Listview (lstAuthorizations_GetData()). Instead it should go to bindData. It seems like its not processing the bValid = true line. Why would it break here? I've tried changing the line to other variations but no matter what it is, it doesn't seem to process in the right order

Code:

```
else //default
{
                    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Search_ANumber) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(Search_MemberID))
                    {
                        bValid = false;
                        errorMsg = "Either A Number or M ID are required";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        bValid = true;
                        lstAuthorizations.FindControl("cColumn").Visible = false; // if not in ActiveExceptions, hide column            //may want to move this to Line 214
                    }
}

if (bValid)
{
                    bindData();
}

protected void bindData()
{
            //removeTextBoxValues(); //remove values from Textboxes since you got a response from the DB
            ShouldSearch = true;
            panelSearchResults.Visible = true;
            lstAuthorizations.DataBind();
}
```

ListView's getdata method:

```
public IQueryable<Project.Data.databaseView> lstAuthorizations_GetData()
    {
        try
        {
            IQueryable<databaseView> query = dbVBA.databaseView.AsQueryable();
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Search_AuthNumber))
            {
                query = query.Where(m => m.A_Number == Search_ANumber);
            }
            return query.OrderBy(a=>a.A_Number);                
        }
```

aspx:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lstAuthorizations" runat="server" 
    ItemPlaceholderID="litPlaceHolder"
    ItemType="Project.Data.databaseView" SelectMethod="lstAuthorizations_GetData">
```

It seems to run the method to get data from the database twice when it actually returns a result (it goes to the lstAuthorizations_GetData() method, then it goes to data bind, then it goes to the lstAuthorizations_GetData() method again). In cases where I try a second value, it goes to the lstAuthorizations_GetData() method, but never goes to bind data.

Anyone know why this is failing?

Comment: where can we find lstAuthorizations_GetData() method? where was it calling?  i think this code segment is not enough to make any kind of analysis.

Comment: I added the code for that. Hopefully thats what you are referring to. that GetData method is for the ListView. It is referenced in the aspx in the ListView at the SelectMethod=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to move hiding/displaying the control AFTER the data was binded. It works now:

```
if (bValid)
                {
                    bindData();                 

                    lstAuthorizations.FindControl("cColumn").Visible = true;
```